# Problem with creating a new session Heroku-Otree

Tags: heroku, pycharm, otree

I created an experiment with Otree (using Pycharm) and would like to put it on the server Heroku. When I test it on localhost everything works fine. However, on Heroku (otree zip uploaded) when I try to create a session I get this message:

```
Failed to create session: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "_gbat_is_connected" of relation "otree_participant" does not exist LINE 1: ...t, _timeout_expiration_time, _timeout_page_index, _gbat_is_c... ^ [SQL: INSERT INTO otree_participant (_vars, session_id, label, id_in_session, payoff, time_started_utc, mturk_assignment_id, mturk_worker_id... etc...
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!